# Children's book where people are brainwashed by starlight

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm guessing I read this sometime in the late 1980s so my recollection is vague to say the least - I'd like to think I didn't imagine it though.

In essence the plot revolves around people being brainwashed/mind controlled when they are exposed to the light from a particular star (probably Sirius but I don't remember for sure). This happens inside some grand house/mansion and at one point our heroes witness it happening, I think by hiding behind furniture within the room the process takes place in.

I seem to remember the protagonists trying to escape in a car but being unable to travel past the town limits, not because they hit a force field or anything but because the car just ends up turned around and heading back into town - this seems like something that works better on television rather than on the page so perhaps this was a novelisation.

Likely to be a UK publication.